# Problem with slideshow in Javascript, images don't load

Tags: javascript, oop, slideshow

I've a problem with a slider I've to do for school.
The console return no error, but the images don't show in the slider. I'm on it for four days now and I can't figure out what is the problem, so it seems that I need your lights ! ^^

I used the console to check if "diaporama.js" is working and it is, the console.log at the end of "slider.js" is to check if my image path is ok and it is. I've absolutely no clue of what is going wrong.

Thank you in advance !

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta property="og:url"          content="" />
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slide.css">
    

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div id="caroussel">
        <img src="" alt="diapo1" id="diapo">
        <div id="precedent" ><</div>
        <div id="suivant" >></div>
    </div>
    <script src="diaporama.js"></script>
    <script src="slide.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

diaporama.js

```
class Diaporama {

    constructor(src, images) {
        this.src = src;
        this.images = images;
        this.position = 0;
        this.start();
    }
    slideLeft() {
        if (this.position <= 0) {
            this.position = this.images.length - 1;
        } else {
            this.position--;
        }
        this.src = this.images[this.position];
    }
    slideRight() {
        if (this.position > this.length-1) {
            this.position = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.position++;
        }
        this.src = this.images[this.position];
    }
    start() {
        this.src = this.images[this.position];
    }

}
```

slide.js

```
var images = Array('img/caroussel1.png', 'img/caroussel2.jpg', 'img/caroussel3.jpg', 'img/caroussel4.jpg', 'img/caroussel5.jpg');

var src = document.getElementById("diapo").src; 

var diaporama = new Diaporama(src, images);

setInterval(function () { diaporama.slideLeft(); }, 5000);

console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum, it looks like *one* problem is that:

1. You have an image element with ID `diapo` in your HTML, and then in the DOM, **which has an empty `src` attribute.**
2. In `slide.js`, you attempt to create a new instance of the class `Diaporama`, called `diaporama`, using the **empty `src` attribute** that you have stored in the variable `src` in `slide.js`.
3. Since an `img` element needs a `src` attribute with an actual URL, in order to show the image at that URL, you are seeing nothing, since **you have not provided a URL** (You won't get an error either, since an empty `src` attribute is perfectly valid HTML, and causes no JS errors)

---

### UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS

The critical issue (or oversight), is that you have:

1. a carousel element in the index.html file, which is then represented in the DOM (which is what we expect)
2. an instance of class `Diaporama` called `diaporama` in `slide.js`, which has **no link to the DOM carousel** that you want it to have: all `diaporama` has is a `String`, taken from the `src` attribute of the DOM carousel, which refers to the URL path of various images. The `diaporama` instance can never "reach out" and update the DOM carousel, given the code you have written.

**Thankfully, the fix is very simple.**

As you know, there needs to be link between the DOM and object that you have created; creating such a link is straight-forward and just involves DOM queries.

I have added a solution (I have placed ALL the JS in one file, rather than two files -- as you have -- but this is not important)

```js
class Diaporama {

  constructor(imgElem, images) {
    this.imgElem = imgElem;
    this.images = images;
    this.position = 0;
    this.start();
  }
  slideLeft() {
    if (this.position <= 0) {
      this.position = this.images.length - 1;
    } else {
      this.position--;
    }
    // this is part of the 'bridge' between "carousel.js" and the DOM
    this.imgElem.src = this.images[this.position];
  }
  slideRight() {
    // there was an error in your original "slideRight" method: a typo and an "off-by-error"
    if (this.position >= this.images.length-1) {
      this.position = 0;
    }
    else {
      this.position++;
    }
    // this is part of the 'bridge' between "carousel.js" and the DOM
    this.imgElem.src = this.images[this.position];
  }
  start() {
    // this is part of the 'bridge' between "carousel.js" and the DOM
    this.imgElem.src = this.images[this.position];
  }

}

// prefer an Array literal rather than call to Array -- less verbose, and slightly faster
var images = ['img/one.jpg', 'img/two.jpg', 'img/three.jpg'];

// This is where 'bridge' between "carousel.js" and the DOM is created: we 'cache' a reference to the carousel 'img' element,
// which we will then modify from within the 'carousel' instance of class Diaporama
var imgElem = window.document.getElementById('carousel').querySelector('img');

var carousel = new Diaporama(imgElem, images);

carousel.start();

// create 'delegated' event listener on document, and trigger correct method of 'carousel' in response to user interaction
window.document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  const target = ev.target;
  if(target.id === 'back_button') {
    carousel.slideLeft();
  } else if(target.id === 'next_button') {
    carousel.slideRight();
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel {
            max-height: 400px;
            max-width: 600px;
            background: rgb(250,250,200);
            overflow: hidden;
 }
 .button-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carousel</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Carousel slider (OOP)</h1>
    <section id="carousel" class="carousel">
       <div class="button-wrapper">
           <button id="back_button">Back</button>
           <button id="next_button">Next</button>
       </div>

        <img src="" alt="carousel image">
    </section>
    <script src="carousel.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps answer your question!

If it does, then please mark my answer as the accepted one.

If you still have questions, then let me know, and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: PS. You have bigger problems with the overall conception of this class and carousel (from my reading of your code, anyways): like, where are you updating the DOM etc?

Comment: About your first message : I've tried to fill the empty src, but the problem is only the image with the chosen src appeared, the others stored in Array don't.

I'm just starting with JS, I'd to do a slider in basic JS (which worked well) and now my task is to transform it in OOP. So I've surely done a lot of mistake, that's why I'm asking for help ! :)
What should I do to fix the conception problem ?

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying: I can try and get back you to in the next day or two, with an overview of how to approach this problem.

Comment: It would be very kind, thank you very much !

Comment: @Panoo I've updated my original answer with a solution to your problem -- let me know if it has answered your question, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for all the explanations and the solution, it solved the problem ! I'm so happy. Thanks a lot again !